# How to deny access to the host by domain name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

How I can to implement next logic in the virtualhost config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias admin.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /usr/.../www

    <Directory /usr/.../www>

        AllowOverride all

        if (%{HTTP_HOST} == 'admin.domain.com') {
            deny from {some ip}
        }

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I need to make admin.explample.com acceseble only from specific IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
    if (%{HTTP_HOST} == 'admin.domain.com') {
        deny from {some ip}
    }
```

with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

where 12.34.56.78 is the IP that you want to **be able to access the host**. All other IPs will cause a 403 Forbidden result.

Comment: thanks man, sorry for the long answer, just was released from prison on parole